# How to get .jpeg from .ashx

Tags: javascript, image, ashx

I have image urls in JavaScript and am trying to save them all onto a single PDF file. I am using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) (JS library to generate PDFs) but it can only take images as .jpegs. Unfortunately the images I have are .ashx. Is there I way I can get convert the .ashx to .jpeg via JavaScript client-side?

Examples of image url:

```
http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=3849&type=card
http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=2923&type=card
http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=36037&type=card
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. javascript cannot manipulate binary content. There's no client-side Javascript support for doing image manipulation.

Comment: What do you mean by 'binary content'? Is .ashx a binary content?